# How to clear and load datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I've  a datagridview and two buttons which get data from sql server DB. Whenever i click on btn1 it fetches the datagridview with the record AND if i then click btn2 it combines the btn2 records with the btn1 records.
How can i clear the datagridview so that btn2 will show me it records and not combinig the records?

Comment: put code, not text !

Comment: set the datasource to null but also if you bind another set of results, it will use that instead of the previous one. Clearing the underlaying dataset is also an option but unnecessarily unless for whatever reason you are reusing that dataset.

Comment: Can you show us what you have for code right now, as it'll help people to give you specific answers to your question, as opposed to general answers.

Comment: Have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear:

```
DataSet.Clear();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clear.aspx

Add below is a example of Populating a datagridview with sql query results.

```
 string select = "SELECT * FROM EXAMPLETABLE";
 Connection c = new Connection();
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c.con); //c.con is the connection string

 SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; 
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```